# iReport + Hibernate Connection throws Invalid Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a Java project which uses `Spring` + `Hibernate` + `JasperReports` to generate a report on PDF format. The report is properly generated using `JasperReports` based on a `.jrxml` file I generated with iReport using a MySQL JDBC connection. On Java code I use `Hibernate/Spring` with annotations. Only using annotations and without the file: `hibernate.cfg.xml` I could create the PDF report after fetching data from MySQL database.

So, Java application works correctly using Hibernate and iRport works correctly using JDBC connection.

The problem is when I try to connect `iReport` to the `MySQL` database with a `Hibernate connection` to take advanatage of the Hibernate functionality. I wanna use the `same Hibernate configuration` who was `successful` on Java.

As I have seen iReport always looks for the file: `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Then I created one on `src/main/resources` (especifically for this purpose) and after build the project it gets copied to: `<project_dir>\target\classes`, and this is the folder I will add to `iReport` classpath below.

The full content of: `hibernate.cfg.xml` is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.elkiosko" />

</beans>
```

To test it, I changed the test method who generates the PDF report to use this XML file, then, I replaced:

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

for:

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

and the PDF report was generated properly too again.

`Going now to iReport...`

I have configured the classpath of iReport adding the folder where the file: `hibernate.cfg.xml` is located on.

[image]

and when trying to set up a Hibernate connection on iReport I get:

`Error - Invalid Configuration`

when click on Test button.

[image]

I also tried checking: `Use Hibernate Annotations` with no success.

I don't understand why with Java the Hibernate connection works but it doesn't with iReport.

Remember I took the way of `annotations` and not `xml`. I created the file: `hibernate.cfg.xml` just to let iReport knows what package scan for configuration.

The mapping of classes are done in the model class as you can see below:

```
package com.elkiosko.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Producto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "stock", nullable = false)
    private int stock;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Producto))
            return false;
        Producto other = (Producto) obj;
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        if (this.id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (!this.name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (this.price != other.price)
            return false;
        if (this.stock != other.stock)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Producto [id=" + id + ", name=" + name +
                ", price=" + price + ", stock=" + stock + "]";
    }

}
```

Also I have other classes implemented, for example: `HibernateConfiguration.java` which is annotated as: `@Configuration` (Java code works OK, the problem is with iReport).

The content of the file: `HibernateConfiguration.java` is as follows:

```
package com.elkiosko.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.elkiosko" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

I have also tried setting up a `Spring loaded Hibernate connection` with no success:

[image]

It seems that it expcets a bean be defined inside `hibernate.cfg.xml`, but I have not defined any bean there because I have defined the `sessionFactory` bean inside the file: `HibernateConfiguration.java`. Anyway, this way is discarded because iReport use an old version of Spring which is incompatible with the version of `Spring` I use: `4.2.0`. So, the only way I can take is create a `Hibernate` connection.

Any idea on how to configure the `Hibernate` connection with `iReport`?